Converting Shapefile to NetCDF - Error "Multipolygon has no len()"
I'm trying to convert a Shapefile that is simply the borders of a country into a NetCDF format for further use in a general circulation model.
As a reference, I used the .SHP.zip file from this website : https://data.humdata.org/dataset/cod-ab-sau
I have the following code
import geopandas as gpd
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np

# Path to the input shapefile and the output NetCDF file
ORIGINAL_SHAPEFILE = "shapefile_of_country.shp"
OUT_NETCDF_FILE = "NetCDF_of_country.nc"  

# Read the shapefile
gdf = gpd.read_file(ORIGINAL_SHAPEFILE)

# Extract geometries and attributes
geometries = gdf.geometry
attributes = gdf.drop(columns='geometry')

# Replace NaN or None with appropriate default values
attributes = attributes.fillna('')  # Replace NaN with empty string

# Determine maximum vertices count
max_vertices = max(len(geom.exterior.coords) if geom.geom_type == 'Polygon' else len(geom) for geom in geometries)

# Create a new NetCDF file
with Dataset(OUT_NETCDF_FILE, 'w', format='NETCDF4') as nc:
   # Create dimensions
   num_features = len(gdf)
   nc.createDimension('features', num_features)
   nc.createDimension('vertices', max_vertices)
   nc.createDimension('coords', 2)

   # Create variables for attributes
   for column in attributes.columns:
       dtype = 'S1' if attributes[column].dtype == 'object' else 'f4' if attributes[column].dtype == 'float' else 'i4'
       nc.createVariable(column, dtype, ('features',))
       nc.variables[column][:] = attributes[column].values.astype(dtype)

   # Create variables for geometry coordinates
   geom_var = nc.createVariable('geometry', 'f4', ('features', 'vertices', 'coords'))

   # Store geometry coordinates
   for i, geom in enumerate(geometries):
       if geom.geom_type == 'Polygon':
           coords = np.array(geom.exterior.coords)
       elif geom.geom_type == 'MultiPolygon':
           # Flatten MultiPolygon to a single list of coordinates
           coords = np.vstack([np.array(part.exterior.coords) for part in geom.geoms])
       else:
           coords = np.array(geom.coords)

       # Reshape coords if necessary to fit into geom_var
       if coords.shape[0] > max_vertices:
           coords = coords[:max_vertices, :]  # Truncate to max_vertices

       geom_var[i, :len(coords), :] = coords
       if len(coords) < max_vertices:
           geom_var[i, len(coords):, :] = np.nan  # Fill remaining with NaNs

print(f'Geometries and attributes have been written to {OUT_NETCDF_FILE}') 

I have tried correcting it many different ways, but i always end up with the following error :
TypeError: object of type 'MultiPolygon' has no len()

What may be the cause of this and is it solvable without changing something from the referenced original shapefile?
